# list directory files recursively with boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, runtime-error, boost-filesystem

I'm using new boost, v1.5.3, to carry out this task like following, thanks to the class recursive_directory_iterator (I don't have to write recursive code):

```
void ListDirRec(const char *Dir, vector<string>& DirFileList, const char* ext)
{    
recursive_directory_iterator rdi(Dir);  
recursive_directory_iterator end_rdi;

DirFileList.empty();

string ext_str0(ext);   
for (; rdi != end_rdi; rdi++)
{
    rdi++;
    //cout << (*di).path().string() << endl;
    cout << (*rdi).path().string() << endl;

    //cout << " <----- " << (*rdi).path().extension() << endl;

    //string ext_str1 = (*rdi).path().extension().string();
    if (ext_str0.compare((*rdi).path().extension().string()) == 0)
    {
        DirFileList.push_back((*rdi).path().string());
    }
}
```

the function list files with specific extension. This function works for cases but frequently return an "assertion fails error" like:

```
**** Internal program error - .... assertion (m_imp.get()) ... operations.hpp(952): dereference of end recursive_directory_iterator
```

I barely figure out the cause of this error. Can any try.. catch help?
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I haven't worked with boost::filesystem at all but shouldn't you assign anything to end_rdi?

Comment: @dutt no, it's fine, the default constructor returns in the end iterator [(docs)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator), just like `std::istream_iterator<T>`

Comment: @ShawnLe - Thank you for this code.  I modified it slightly to suit my needs, but this was very useful to help recursively find files in a directory that match an extension.

Comment: `DirFileList.empty();` does nothing. It returns true if DirFileList is empty. If you want to erase all elements, use `clear()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incrementing `rdi` inside the loop as well as in the `for` declaration:

```
for (; rdi != end_rdi; rdi++)
{
    rdi++;
```

That means that `rdi` might be `end_rdi` (the end-iterator, which means past the last element) within your loop. Is there any reason you're doing this? (If this is intentional, you should check to make sure `rdi != end_rdi` again after you increment it.)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
recursive_directory_iterator dir(path(Dir));
for(auto&& i : dir) {
    if (is_directory(i)) {
        //Do whatever you want
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```