# Can you generate a log file that would display certain criteria about a folders content?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to create a program that will read the file contents of a folder and export the  name, size, and last date modified to a single "log" file.
My question I guess is; Is it possible to export all this information into a log and would having multiple sub-folders in the directory affect this?  If this is possible how would one go about doing this?

Comment: This can of course be accomplished.  You can do it in a cross platform manner, if you are willing to use boost.  See this related question for an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182980/list-directory-files-recursively-with-boostfilesystem

Comment: sounds like reinventions of `dir /s >output.log` command line command

Comment: @Roman: except that it does not work on Unix and you may not want to use an external process call inside a native C++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is all possible. I am a bit biased, so I would suggest a QtCore based solution, but this would work very nicely cross-platform, or you could even log a lot more than just this. See the three main classes that could help, below.

QFileInfo

- file name: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#fileName
- size: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#size
- last modified: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#lastModified

QFile (inheriting QIODevice)

- read all: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#readAll

QDir

- info entry list: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdir.html#entryInfoList

If for some reason, you would not like to use QtCore, you can probably also copy and paste the relevant methods out with their source code dependencies from this directory:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/trees/stable/src/corelib/io